# Am I able to clone Windows XP 32-bit to my new custom PC, and then upgrade it to Windows 7 Pro 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, backup, upgrade

I have an old 32-bit Windows XP computer. I had just custom built a new PC that doesn't have any OS installed. I want to use an external Hard Drive to clone my current Windows XP Operating System, and then use that for my new PC. Then I'd like to use the [Windows 7 Pro 64-bit upgrade](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/pd/productID.216644200?Icid=Student_HUB_4up_Windows)

Is this possible? Also, what kind of software should I use to clone my old PC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the old XP wont run on the new computer . Even if it did its considered piracy as you don't have the right to NORMALLY transfer licenses from computers( exceptions do exist , but you need to have the original XP installation CD , and reactivate it with tech support on the new machine ) .

The easiest thing to do is to just buy a full version of Windows 7 and install that on your new PC .

Plus you can't upgrade a 32-bit installation to 64bit , and your new PC PROBABLY has more then 4 gb of ram( or you at least want to option to upgrade this latter ).

PS : Home Premium does most of the same stuff as Professional windows, and you can buy Home Premium  FULL for about 100$-maybe a bit more . I added this since I assume your trying to save money .

Comment: What if my current computer is about to die and I just want to transfer everything over including the data.

Comment: Just keep the old hard drive , and install it in your new PC as a secondary drive... Do this after installing windows 7 - you might have to go into BIOS to tell your PC to boot the new hard drive first . Anyway, this way you keep all your data and access it when ever you need it .. 
Or use User State Migration as Dave has suggested , although since I've never used this tool i'm not sure how much data will actually be moved

Answer (score 2):

There is no upgrade from Windows XP to Windows 7.  Your only option is a clean install.  You might upgrade from XP to Vista and then WIN7 but there could be license issues as noted by @Keithsoulasa

In any case a clean install would be best.

You can export data using the User State Migration Tool in XP  Apps will not be moved.  Called Easy Transfer in Windows 7